# Debian : unable to install packages with apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

I am using Debian Jessie.
When I try to install gedit I have the following issue :

```
XXX@XXX:~$ sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit : Depends: python3-gi-cairo (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that I face similar issues when trying to install other packages, it's not only with Gedit.

My source.list file :

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.2.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 lxde-CD Binary-1 20150906-11:10]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.2.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 lxde-CD Binary-1 20150906-11:10]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main

#deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

# testing
#deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
#deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main 

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

The directory sources.list.d is empty.

**Edit :**

I tried :

```
XXX@XXX:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for XXX: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless firebird2.5-common
  firebird2.5-common-doc firebird2.5-server-common fonts-opensymbol
  java-common libabw-0.1-1 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libboost-date-time1.58.0 libboost-filesystem1.55.0 libboost-system1.55.0
  libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libe-book-0.1-1
  libeot0 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfbclient2
  libfbembed2.5 libglew1.10 libgltf-0.0-0v5 liblangtag-common liblangtag1
  libmhash2 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libodfgen-0.1-1 libraptor2-0
  librasqal3 librdf0 libsctp1 libwps-0.4-4 libyajl2 lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jre
  openjdk-7-jre-headless tzdata-java uno-libs3 ure
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

and then try to install again, but got the same error message.

**Edit 2:**

```
XXX@XXX~$  sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  openssl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What packages have you frozen?

Comment: "you have held broken packages." Try first: sudo apt-get -f install Or if you have Synaptic go Synaptic> Edit>Fix Broken Packages ---the try again.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how I can know wich package I have frozen ?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it does not return anything

Comment: No held packages. Try to fix the errors as arochester suggested then.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I tried (see my edit) but it does not work

Comment: When you have tried : sudo apt-get -f install you have only ended up with packages to autoremove: sudo apt-get autoremove. Continue with sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade That should shake things out. Then try: sudo apt-get install gedit again

Comment: @arochester I have just done it: autoremove did remove some packages, but then still the error message :(

Comment: added  sudo apt-get upgrade output: openssl has been kept back. Maybe it's related to my issue?

Comment: Run this:
sudo apt-get -qyf install && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -qy update && sudo apt-get -qy upgrade && sudo apt-get -qy clean && sudo apt-get -qy autoremove
Afterwards:
sudo apt-get install -y gedit